# Subscribe to observable data held in dataservice

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable, ionic4

I have an ionic 4 app this retrieves faults from an endpoint. I want to keep the data in a property on the service.

So I can access the list on multiple screens also it means every time the first screen is loaded I don't have to reload the list

My fault service is below. I call `updateFaults` that retrieves the faults and stores them in `this.faults`.

```
export class FaultsService {

  private selectedFault: Fault;
  public faults: Fault[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   updateFaults() {
       this.http.get<Fault[]>('/api/faults').subscribe((data: any) =>
       {
         this.faults = data.data
       })
    }

    getFaultObservable() : Observable<Fault[]>
    {
      return of(this.faults)
    }

}
```

And in my page `ngOnInit` I have this method :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.faultsService.getFaultObservable().subscribe((faults: Fault[]) =>{
        console.log('update faults')
      this.faults = faults
      }
    )
```

But when I load the page, although it doesn't error. Nothing is displayed and the console.log is not fired. So I am not sure I am subscribed correctly.

Comment: `faults` is `undefined` in the service. Areyou calling `updateFaults` at any time?

Comment: Did you try adding a console.log() inside your subscribe to the http get

Comment: sorry, should have said. I call that on the ngOnInit for the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service can cache the retrieved items and then return the items to any subsequent calls wrapped in an observable using [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html). The service itself can cache the result of the call using [`tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html).

You should keep the caching abstracted from the caller so keep the retrieval to 1 method. The caller then calls `getFaults()` and subscribes to the returned observable. It does not matter if it is the 1st time or the 10nth time as far as the caller is concerned.

```
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export class FaultsService {

  faults: Fault[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getFaults() : Observable<Fault[]> {
    return this.faults
        ? of(this.faults)
        : this.http.get<{data: Fault[]}>('/api/faults')
              .pipe(tap((data) => this.faults = data.data) // cache
                  , map((data) => data.data)); // return just Fault[] from data.data to the subscriber
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, this.faults is returned with the model data.data in side it. I tried change the tap to  this.faults = data.data but it still reports it as this.faults.data

Comment: @JaChNo - `this.http.get<{data: Fault[]}>('/api/faults').pipe(tap((data) => this.faults = data.data))`. Make sure you are using a new build (ng serve or ng build --watch) once you change the implementation. Also the generic argument would need to be changed on the http get call.

Comment: @JaChNo - one more fix I added to ensure that the original subscription also returns `Fault[]` and not `{ data: Fault[] }`.

Comment: Winner! that does it. thanks very much. the first edit was still returning fault.data

Comment: @JaChNo glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better way to go, so you don't have to call update. You can just cache the first time, then return the cache each additional time. I added an invalidate cache in case you want to do that sometimes.

```
export class FaultsService {

  private selectedFault: Fault;
  private faults: Fault[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getFaultObservable() : Observable<Fault[]>
    {
      if(this.faults) {
          return of(this.faults)
      }


      return this.http.get<Fault[]>('/api/faults').pipe(
   tap(data => this.faults = data.data)
      )
    }

    invalidateCache() {
       this.faults = null;
    }

}
```